# Problema sobre emberJS y polyfills

Tags: javascript, npm, bower, ember.js

me clone un proyecto de ember y al correrlo me arroja el siguiente error:

```
loader.js:247 Uncaught Error: Could not find module `@ember/polyfills` imported from `radio/initializers/viewport-config`
    at missingModule (loader.js:247)
    at findModule (loader.js:258)
    at Module.findDeps (loader.js:168)
    at findModule (loader.js:262)
    at requireModule (loader.js:24)
    at index.js:18
    at Array.forEach (<anonymous>)
    at exports.default (index.js:15)
    at Module.callback (app.js:13)
    at Module.exports (loader.js:106)
```

Previamente habia instalado el cliente de ember, phantomJS e hice tanto un bower install como npm install de los siguientes archivos:

Package.json:

```
{
  "name": "radio",
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "description": "Small description for radio goes here",
  "private": true,
  "directories": {
    "doc": "doc",
    "test": "tests"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "build": "ember build",
    "start": "ember server",
    "test": "ember test",
    "deploy": "**",
    "deploy-prod": "**"
  },
  "repository": "",
  "engines": {
    "node": ">= 0.10.0"
  },
  "author": "",
  "license": "MIT",
  "devDependencies": {
    "broccoli-asset-rev": "^2.4.2",
    "broccoli-sass": "^0.7.0",
    "ember-ajax": "^2.0.1",
    "ember-cli": "2.7.0",
    "ember-cli-app-version": "^1.0.0",
    "ember-cli-babel": "^5.1.6",
    "ember-cli-bourbon": "1.2.2",
    "ember-cli-dependency-checker": "^1.2.0",
    "ember-cli-google-analytics": "1.5.0",
    "ember-cli-htmlbars": "^1.0.3",
    "ember-cli-htmlbars-inline-precompile": "^0.3.1",
    "ember-cli-inject-live-reload": "^1.4.0",
    "ember-cli-jshint": "^1.0.0",
    "ember-cli-meta-tags": "3.0.1",
    "ember-cli-moment-shim": "2.2.1",
    "ember-cli-pace": "0.1.0",
    "ember-cli-qunit": "^2.0.0",
    "ember-cli-release": "^0.2.9",
    "ember-cli-slick": "1.0.14",
    "ember-cli-sri": "^2.1.0",
    "ember-cli-test-loader": "^1.1.0",
    "ember-cli-uglify": "^1.2.0",
    "ember-data": "^2.7.0",
    "ember-export-application-global": "1.1.1",
    "ember-lazy-image": "0.0.15",
    "ember-load-initializers": "^0.5.1",
    "ember-local-storage": "1.3.1",
    "ember-moment": "6.1.0",
    "ember-resize": "0.0.17",
    "ember-resolver": "^2.0.3",
    "ember-responsive": "1.2.7",
    "ember-social": "0.3.0",
    "ember-youtube": "0.8.2",
    "liquid-fire": "0.24.1",
    "loader.js": "^4.0.1"
  }
}
```

y el bower.json tiene lo siguiente:

```
{
  "name": "radio",
  "dependencies": {
    "ember": "~2.7.0",
    "ember-cli-shims": "0.1.1",
    "ember-qunit-notifications": "0.1.0",
    "bourbon": "4.2.6",
    "slick-carousel": "^1.6.0",
    "pace": "^1.0.2",
    "blob-polyfill": "^1.0.20150320"
  }
}
```

He estado instalando por medio de npm / bower varias librerias para solucionar problemas sobre polyfills pero no encontre una solución, alguien sabe como podria solucionar este problema? saludos.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

El problema es que tu Ember está en la versión 2.7.0, según tu `package.json`, y `@ember/polyfills` fue introducido en la versión 2.16.0. La última, por cierto, es la 3.1.

Actualizar Ember.js no es demasiado difícil, particularmente dado que no tienes que tocar el proyecto en sí. Te aconsejo mirar la documentación de Ember.js, pero normalmente basta con `npm install --save-dev ember-cli`